# permission denied when importing database on my ubuntu

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu

I got a permission denied when i tried to load a .sql file in commandline.

```
mysql -u root -p DBname < <path to .sql>
bash: <path to .sql> : permission denied
```

newbie from the system I do not know why is it. the database .sql came from automysql backup.

Comment: check the permissions of your .sql file

Comment: thanks! I already change the permission using thunar.....

Comment: did it work? do you have spaces in your .sql filename?

Comment: I think yes, there are no spaces on the filename. then tried mysql imports then ask password.